# Search bar on click go to link

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a search bar which suggests users from a database. Currently when clicking on a username nothing really happens, the username goes to the searchbar, but how do i make it so that when clicking the username it goes to a link and adds the username behind it.

example: www.test.com/user.php?u= ((the username))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can `data` return multiple values/username for a search? If yes then add the output of `data` to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to a page by changing the `window.location.href` value. So, you could do something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    window.location.href = 'www.test.com/user.php?u=' + $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Even better, if we do need to change page why not cut the $(this) parts and directly do the relocation of the page?

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that. Since we are navigating away from the current page, it seems that setting the value of the input and emptying the results is unnecessary. The reason why I didn't delete it is because the code was already present in the original question and I do not have enough context to know if that code is meaningful to the person who posted the question.